# Open API v 3.0 Java Annotations Still being called .io.swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, springfox, microprofile

I am only getting started with openapi/swagger.

I understand that Swagger APIs have been Open Sources and that they are now called OpenAPI. I also understand that in the new specs all references to *swagger* has been replaced with *openapi*. ( Eg:- "swagger": "2.0" --> "openapi": "3.0.0" )

However, when I look at the Java Open API v3 Annotations, I do not see any such standardization. Each vendor seems to be creating their own annotations. For example, I see **org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.Operation** from microprofile while Swagger's *codegen* generates **io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation**.

Is my reading correct in that openapi has not yet been standardized at the java level?

or did I get this all wrong?